# What is this type of sort called?

Tags: sorting

For example, a list of strings:

```
The Foo
A Bar
```

To remove the leading "The" and "A" and sort by the remaining characters, what is that type of sort called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific name for such sort. Apply normalization (remove articles, switch to the same case) and then, likely, sort lexicographically